# Assigning PHP class fields to array values when passing both into a function doesn't set the fields, why?

Tags: php, arrays, function, object

As the description states, I have a function that takes in an array and an object as arguments and assigns all of the objects fields to their respective values in the array depending on the type of the object.  The objects all have different fields, but they all have a type attribute which the function uses to determine which fields to assign.

It works something like this:

```
function unload($arr,&$obj){ <-- //&$obj not $obj
  if($obj->type == 'A'){
    echo 'Setting field for A';
    $obj->a = $arr['a_value'];
    //some more assignments..
  }
  elseif($obj->type == 'B'){
    $obj->b = $arr['b_value'];
    echo 'Setting field for B';
    //some more assignments...
  }
  //some more elseifs
  //return an error if
  //object's type doesn't
  //match
  else{
    echo 'Error: Object type '.$obj->type.' not recognized.';
  }

}

$arr['a_value'] = 'SomeValue';
$arr['b_value'] = 'SomeOtherValue';
$obj = new A(); //A's type set to 'A' upon initialization
unload($arr,$obj);
echo 'A->a set to:  '.$obj->a;
```

Output:
    A->a set to:

The code enters the correct branch for the object that is passed in but none of the object's fields get assigned.  What am I doing wrong?

The server is running PHP 4.4.7, I still have no idea what's causing this.

Edit: I FINALLY figured it out, it was a combination of 2 things:

I didn't realize the `$this` keyword was required when referencing class field names from within the class.  I assumed the variables had global scope so `$this` was optional like it is in Java.  This is why just changing the function declaration didn't fix the problem.  Now everything works fine!

Comment: Are they `private` in the object?

Comment: can't see any abvious errors.. could you create a simple test case and include it in your question? Note that rather than have a ->type function you could use `instanceof` (e.g. `if($obj instanceof SomeClass) { ...`

Comment: @Hamish Yeah that would work, but the `type` property *may* be something irrelevant of what class it is.

Comment: @alex true, just thought it was worth a mention.

Comment: The type property is behaving as it should so I know it's picking the right object.  The objects are declared using 'var' which according to the manual defaults to public.

Comment: Please write the entire code, especially the part regarding the error if object type doesn't match. It seems thatr there are problems with error outputting. Are notice avaible? or have you set error_reporting to 0?

Comment: `A->a` isn't going to return anything. The object is `$obj`.

Comment: ^ Thanks for pointing out the typo, I fixed it and added the final 'else' condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which PHP version are you on?

Because in PHP4 you need to explicitly pass the object by reference:

```
function unload($arr,&$obj){
```

If otherwise you are on PHP5, double check your `$arr` contents. And do some `print_r` inside and outside the function ...

Comment: Didn't work.  I'm echoing out the array to make sure the values are being stored and they are (this is just a test page so I'm setting everything manually).

Comment: Just tried printing the array with print_r from within the function, everything is passed in correctly.  For whatever nothing gets assigned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to get the class name i'd suggest you to use `get_class()` which will return the class name.
- Anyway why are you using `A->a` instead of `$obj->a`? It seems to be wrong.
- And notice that `switch` could best suits your needs in this case.

**EDIT** Finally got it: you have to replace

```
$arr['a'] = 'SomeValue';
$arr['b'] = 'SomeOtherValue';
```

with

```
$arr['a_value'] = 'SomeValue';
$arr['b_value'] = 'SomeOtherValue';
```

or otherwise set `$obj->b = $arr['a_value'];` to `$obj->b = $arr['a'];` and do the same with the b value.
The meaning of this is that the array keys have to be the same.

Comment: I fixed the typo and added in print statements above (already had these in my code).  Setting error_reporting doesn't change anything.  I know I could have done this as a switch, I'm just used to C/Java where you can only do case-switch on primitives

Comment: Setting error reporting will change! It will print a Notice error in case the variable $obj->a is not correctly set. What's the output now?

Comment: Wow sorry I didn't catch that in my example, all of the fields do match in my actual code.  I tried changing one of them so it would mismatch and still didn't get any error/warning, I'm calling error_reporting(1) at the top of my code after my includes.

Comment: So you choose the other answer? I mean... i did tried the code you posted and make that changes: it works.